# nvidia-smi hangs indefinitely: what could be the issue?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I try to run [`nvidia-smi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/alt-nvidia-current-smi.1.html) from the shell on a machine, but it hangs indefinitely: what could be the issue?

---

Update (2016-08-09): Since this question received no answer, I crossposted it:

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/955951/linux/nvidia-smi-hangs-indefinitely-what-could-be-the-issue-/ ;
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-could-be-the-issue-when-nvidia-smi-hangs-indefinitely

Comment: In the instances when I've seen this happen, the problem seemed to have been due to internal NVIDIA driver weirdness that went away in a later driver/CUDA revision.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489070/nvidia-smi-process-hangs-and-cant-be-killed-with-sigkill-either

Answer (score -1):

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/942116/system-hangs-when-issuing-quot-nvidia-smi-q-quot-command-after-installing-cuda/ advises the following (when using an EC2 instance):

> My suggestion would be:
>
> 1. start over with a clean OS load
> 2. Follow the instructions for "runfile installer method" in the cuda 7.5 linux install guide. Don't skip any steps or fail to remove nouveau. Follow the instructions carefully.
> 3. Select "no" when prompted to install the driver after launching the CUDA 7.5 runfile installer.
> 4. Download the 361.45 driver runfile installer.
> 5. Install that driver.
> 6. Profit.